Relevant email suggestions in Apple Mail
I have the impression that the email suggestions presented by Apple Mail are much less relevant than they used to be. Specifically, I am encountering two problems:

It happens very often that I start typing the name of someone who sent me an email a few years ago and Mail fails to autocomplete it. When I then search for the person's email using the "search" function it invariably turns up, so it's not just that it was deleted.
My organisation has quite a few staff (around 6000) and uses Exchange. As a consequence, whatever name I start typing, I get dozens of irrelevant suggestions of people I've never heard of pulled from our central Exchange server.

My question is therefore twofold. How can I tell Mail.app not to pull email addresses from the Exchange server and how can I make sure that it uses all my old emails (not just recent ones) to look for addresses in its autocomplete function? It seems to me that this is how it used to work, so I am hoping that there is still some hidden preference allowing to tweak this behaviour.
